# Git merge between two repositories where one has the code in a sub folder

Tags: git

I'd like to merge between two git repositories which don't exactly have the same directory structure.
In repository A the code is in a sub folder and I want to merge that in repository B where the code is in the top level folder.

A/sub/* -> B/*

How can I achieve that?

*edit*
I solved it by creating format-patches and removing the path prefixes via sed.

Comment: Did you try a simple merge? It should work in non-complicated cases.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [subtree merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) :

> The idea of the subtree merge is that you have two projects, and one of the projects maps to a subdirectory of the other one and vice versa.